# Having only a JAR Maven Archetype file, how can it be generated a new project?

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, maven-archetype

I'm just starting with Maven 3 for an Scala project in IntelliJ.

I have generated a JAR file following [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html) guide.

I moved archetype.jar to a directory in where I want to create a new project. But my questions are:

1. Is this file stand-alone? Is it enough? It does not work with the command "mvn archetype:generate"
2. Is it possible to use the jar file without the intervention of any repository? So I can share it with collegues.
3. What's the best method for this, I've been reseaching and all the guides are based on repositories only and not in working local. Even the local repositories only consists in xmls files with the id but not the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally used the following command before generating:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-jar-archetype-file> -DgroupId=<groupId> -DartifactId=<artifactId> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=jar
```

After executing the command, the jar is installed in your local repo. You can generate the project with for instance IntelliJ or go to the path where you want to generate the project and...

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sort of complex question you are asking...I am going to try summarise what I know and let's see if it helps.

Answers to your questions:

1) If you have just the basic Maven Project structure after you have generated the archtype and so on, if you run maven clean install and the project produces a jar, this in theory should be immediately executable from the command line and standalone.

However, as you add dependencies to your small projects, not all dependencies are automatically built into the standalone jar, sometimes you have to tell maven to bundle them into it.

**Maven Shade Plugin - adds all the needed dependencies into your jar**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>MainApp</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                </transformers>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <shadedClassifierName>launcher</shadedClassifierName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

2) You do not need to integrate to any repository, its recommended for wider projects so that you can publish artifacts to your firms Repo for eas of use between developers

3) The easiest method is to create a new project in Intellij itself specifying Maven as the project type and that will give you the default project structure. In the pom file you then specify the build block I pasted above and you are essentially good to go...If you need Dependencies also t run your own code you will need to add them in a Dependencies block.

Comment: Thanks @RobertSquire but, what can I do to generate a new project based on the archetype jar file?

Comment: You can just create a new Maven Intellij project, and then specify the packaging as jar? I am pretty sure this is what you want

Comment: My doubt was, - ok, I have a archetype.jar file, now what can I do with this to generate a project